# Ubuntu 12.04 Suspend not working

Tags: suspend

Suspend mode is not working on my computer. When I suspend my PC, Shortly it comes back to its previous state. Motherboard is Asus P5N-MX

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Can you please add some more details so your question can be answer properly

Answer (score 0):

When trying to turn the state suspend state the screen goes black, and after one second computer returns to the desktop.My motherboard is Asus P5N-MX